# Creating SQL connection using VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to connect VB.net to SQL server to fetch some information, I got connection script from Microsoft Technet but it gives login failed for user: domain\user. Although the account had dbowner permission and is also a service account. From same machine I have successfully created connection between powershell and Sql database.

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    'Create ADO.NET objects.
    Private myConn As SqlConnection
    Private myCmd As SqlCommand
    Private myReader As SqlDataReader
    Private results As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Create a Connection object.
        myConn = New SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=VMdbInventory;" & _
                "Data Source=MONITORING\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;")

        'Create a Command object.
        myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand
        myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from vmonhost"

        'Open the connection.
        myConn.Open()

        myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

        'Concatenate the query result into a string.
        Do While myReader.Read()
            results = results & myReader.GetString(0) & vbTab & _
                    myReader.GetString(1) & vbLf
        Loop
        'Display results.
        MsgBox(results)



        'Close the reader and the database connection.
        myReader.Close()
        myConn.Close()



    End Sub
End Class
```

Any Idea what I am missing here?

Comment: what's the exact error message? what's the user attempting to connect? is there a domain or you are dealing with standalone machines?

Comment: When you say "the account had dbowner permission", you mean you right? Because this "Integrated Security=SSPI" is in the connection string which means it will connect as the user running the application.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot open database "VMdbInventory" requested by the login. The login failed.

Login failed for user 'Domain\user'.

Comment: Yes, I am using same account to run the application which has dbowener right on the SQL server database, I am using domain, My system is a dev machine and Sql server is installed in another machine ...

Comment: Are you able to use SSMS to open the database from your machine with your Windows account?

Comment: Yes, I am able to open database from my Dev machine, all SQL related services are also running including browser.. initially i had a problem with connection but after turning off firewall i am able to connect

Comment: Are you sure it's using the right user?  Try adding `Integrated Security=SSPI;
User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword`

Comment: Have you tried connecting to this database by adding (and confirming) a connection string in your project settings?

Comment: Side note: Don't Dim the SqlClient objects in the usual sense of variables. Look into the `Using` statement.

Comment: Hi yes, connection string seems to be fine, as its able to connect to sql server but unable to login, if i change the connection string it shows error cannot find instance specified or network error occurred. Also tried Geoff suggestion but same error i am getting. 
Is there some windows component which are required to be opened or any DLL or connection needed to be imported for successful login? I am using VS 2012 express.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the issue, on sql server i was getting error like only windows authentication was enabled, changed it to mixed mode then also error was ther. Then  finally changed connection string in code to `Integrated Security=SSPI; User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword`

Its working like a charm now..

Comment: If you are using Integration Security then you do not actually need to include the Username and Password in the connection string.  Your application will take the context of the user who is logged into the machine (eg. PC / laptop) and authenticate with the SQL Server