# SQL Server connection failing in VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

[image]

I want to connect to an SQL Server database. I am not experienced.

This part is a gray:

> Imports System.Data.SqlClient

```
Public Class Conec

    Dim cnx As New sql << here there is no SqlConnection

End Class
```

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour]. Then have a look at this sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483423/creating-sql-connection-using-vb-net

Comment: Just continue typing, e.g. "sqlcon" and the SqlConnection object will show up in IntellisSense. Don't stop at "sql" like in your screenshot. Don't get fooled by the alphabetic ordering which appears to imply that SqlConnection isn't present. Apparently IntelliSense prioritizes the results hierarchically. So unless you typed the "c" of Connection", it doesn't bother to search further down the object hierarchy, which in this case would be within SqlClient. If you're unsure where an object is located, hit "F2" to start the Object Browser and search for the desired object there.

Comment: Before you carry on typing without knowing, you should be aware that it is not a good idea to make one SqlConnection for the whole program. Instead, make a new SqlConnection for each query. The [documentation for SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection) shows how to do that.